# Executing stored procedure of sql client. By the method i am habituated in

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I used to follow this method to execute SQL Server agent queries

```
Public connection As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)

Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Dim sqlquery As String = "insert into tbluserdetails (username,password,usertype) values (@username,@password,@usertype)"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(connectionstring, connection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", cbousertype.Text)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub End Class
```

Now I want to execute the stored procedure `sp_saurav` that has 5 parameters. Using same method is it possible? I googled for this but there are very different codes shown.

I would be grateful if someone could help me execute stored procedure with identical code as shown above.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `CommandType` property of the `SqlCommand` object to the value `StoredProcedure` and set the procedure name as the value for `CommandText` property.

```
Dim connString As String = "connectionstring"
Dim sqlquery As String = "procedure_name"

Using conn As New SqlConnection(connString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = sqlquery

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", value1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", value2)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", value3)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", value4)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param5", value5)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. This answer helped me. Sir i resently migrated from VB6 to VB.NET. No ideas regarding C#. If it is possible for you please write those few lines in VB.net.

Comment: Apologies I did not notice the vb.net tag. Updated the answer with VB.NET code sample. Please check